# Why are there CSS rules using -9999px

Tags: css

On the Twitter site, I found the following CSS rules:

```
.ProfileCanopy-headerBg img {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: -9999px;
  bottom: -9999px;
  margin: auto 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

What could be the reason for the limit -9999px?

Comment: it hides it off screen, on the presumption that the 0,0 origin of most peoples' monitors will stay at the top left, and not someday migrate to the bottomright, which would make those things visible once screens exceed 10k x 10k in resolution.

Comment: Here's a great explanation on the history of -9999px: http://www.zeldman.com/2012/03/01/replacing-the-9999px-hack-new-image-replacement/

Comment: This might be interesting: [How can I replicate {background-size: cover}...](https://redditing.net/r/webdev/comments/2ddb7q)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a way to hide an element that still allows screen readers (and similar technologies) to read the contents, unlike if you were to use, say, `display: none`.

The value `9999px` is arbitrary. Can be any negative number really but I guess it feels safer to really shove it far away :P